# How to Continue when No such Element

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, element

I would like to verify an object exists.  In the example below the actual element :id is "all-tab", I set it to "all2-tab" to see if the FAILED notification would be shown.  However I receive a No such element error and the script stops.

BTW I'm using ruby.

...response.rb:51:in `assert_ok': Unable to find element with id == alll-tab (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError)

```
#View All Events Tab Exists
option = driver.find_element(:id,"all2-tab").displayed? #exists? 
if option == true
  puts"View All Events Tab Exists: PASS"
else
  puts"!!FAILED View All Events Tab Does not Exists"
end
```

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `begin` and `rescue`:

```
begin
    option = driver.find_element(:id,"all2-tab").displayed? #exists? 
    if option == true
      puts"View All Events Tab Exists: PASS"
    else
      puts"!!FAILED View All Events Tab Does not Exists"
    end
rescue
    puts"Element does not exist"
end
```

Comment: Thank you Richard.  I saw some posts discussing rescue, but I had no idea what it was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the code in a exception handler , like

```
begin
  # something which might raise an exception
rescue ExceptionClass => some_variable
end
```